# Is a mutating admission webhook able the change the resource's group, version or kind

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to know if it is possible for a mutating admission webhook to change the api group, api version or kind of the resource that triggered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nope** - attempted conversion from one kind to another, e.g. *Deployment* to *Daemonset* or *ConfigMap* to *Secret*, always leads to an "unknown conversion" error (tested on Minikube),